# Export/list out object information as text format

Tags: objects, export, dimensions

Is there an option in blender to export (or list out) certain properties of all (selected) objects?

My case is: I have modelled a furniture using real size, metric measurements. Now I want to hand a list of sheet sizes over (x-y-z dimensions of objects in blender) to the carpenter so he would be able to cut the correct sheets for me.

I am looking for an option to do all inside blender, if that isn't possible, an option of some kind of export would be acceptable.

Comment: You could get some help from this addon/script (never tried, though)
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Neuro_tool/Measurement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's pretty easy with if you know a little Python.

```
# import the necessary modules we need
# in our case, blender's python API and python's os module
import bpy, os

# get the current selection
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

# initialize a blank result variable
result = ""

# iterate through the selected objects
for sel in selection:
    # get the current object's dimensions
    dims = sel.dimensions
    # write the selected object's name and dimensions to a string
    result += "%s - %.03fm x %.03fm x %.03fm\n" % (sel.name, dims.x, dims.y, dims.z)

# get path to render output (usually /tmp\)
tempFolder = os.path.abspath (bpy.context.scene.render.filepath)
# make a filename
filename = os.path.join (tempFolder, "newfile.txt")
# confirm path exists
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
# open a file to write to
file = open(filename, "w")
# write the data to file
file.write(result)
# close the file
file.close()
```

Copy and paste the above into Blender's Text editor and press *Run Script* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). It will save the data *(object name and dimensions)* into your `tmp` folder.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I have just tried to run the script and it says "Python script fail. Look in the console for now.."

Comment: great script, but may be unit scale is missing of the scene.

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted it to do, except I replaced `selection = bpy.context.selected_objects` with
`selection = scene.data.objects` and used a *Find and Replace All* function in my text editor on the output file to replace the punctuation with commas to make it valid CSV, and imported into Libreoffice Calc.

Comment: how about in inches? :)