# How do I create a text file from the selected objects containing name and collection?

Tags: python, objects, export, collections

I'm trying to do something similar as in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40666/export-list-out-object-information-as-text-format) post, but instead of all dimensions from each object I want to know to which collection they belong.

The part of the code I changed was:

```
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

# iterate through the selected objects
for sel in selection:
    # get collection to which the object belongs
    col = bpy.context.collection
    # write the selected object's name and dimensions to a string
    result += "%s, %s" % (sel.name, col.name)
```

However, this seems to loop over the collections that are inside of the selected objects instead of the other way around. How do I change my code to see the collection the objects belongs to?

Comment: Pretty close but the collection name would be the same for all objects (`context.collection` is the active one). How to get the collection of the object: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134789/31447

Comment: That works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out:

```
import bpy


for eachCol in bpy.data.collections:
    
    print("Collection:", eachCol.name)
    
    for eachObject in eachCol.objects:
        
        print("  ", eachObject.name)
```

Test result:

[image]

or if you only want the info about the selected objects:

```
import bpy

selected = bpy.context.selected_objects

for eachSel in selected: 

    for eachCol in bpy.data.collections:
        for eachObject in eachCol.objects:
            
            if eachObject == eachSel:
            
                print(eachObject.name, "is in", eachCol.name)
```

test result:

[image]